# add new column based on two other columns with several conditions, character

Tags: r, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, addition

I would like to add a new column to my dataframe based on two other columns. The data looks as follows:

```
df
job    honorary  

yes    yes
yes    no
no     yes
yes    yes
yes    NA
NA     no
```

Now I would like a third column that contains "both" if job and honorary are yes, "honorary" if only the column honorary contains a yes, "job" if only the column job contains a yes, and NA if both contain NA or one column contains NA and the other no. The third column should look like this:

```
result

both
job
honorary
both
job
NA
```

I have tried code with if and mutate but I am quite new to R and my codes do not work at all.
If I assign values singularly like:

```
data_nature_fewmissing$urbandnat[data_nature_fewmissing$nature =="yes" & data_nature_fewmissing$urbangreen =="yes"] <- "yes"
```

It is not working because in every step I overwrite the results from before.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like `case_when` from `dplyr` for these types of complex conditionals.

```r
df<-tibble::tribble(
   ~job, ~honorary,
  "yes",     "yes",
  "yes",      "no",
   "no",     "yes",
  "yes",     "yes",
  "yes",        NA,
     NA,      "no"
  )

library(dplyr)

df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(result=case_when(
    job=="yes" & honorary=="yes" ~ "both",
    honorary=="yes" ~ "honorary", 
    job=="yes" ~ "job", 
    is.na(honorary) & is.na(job) ~ NA_character_, 
    is.na(honorary) & job=="no" ~ NA_character_, 
    is.na(job) & honorary=="no" ~ NA_character_, 
    TRUE ~ "other"
  ))

df_new
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   job   honorary result  
#>   <chr> <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 yes   yes      both    
#> 2 yes   no       job     
#> 3 no    yes      honorary
#> 4 yes   yes      both    
#> 5 yes   <NA>     job     
#> 6 <NA>  no       <NA>
```

or in base R

```
df_new<-df

df_new=within(df_new,{
  result=NA
  result[ honorary=="yes"] = "honorary"
  result[ job=="yes"] = "job"
  result[job=="yes" & honorary=="yes"]='both'
})
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @Joe Erinjeri, nice! Just curious, could you also come up with a solution that solely uses base `R`? One could use multiple `ifelse` statements, but there must be a more efficient way...

Comment: added a base r solution. Note that using within in base r, it assigns the values to the dataframe for each condition in the within group. so you are basically overwriting the NA that are initially set. That's why i like the dplyr solution, since its a more tidy way of writing multiple if else.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns an error because you have not indexed the rows. When indexing a dataframe, the syntax is `df[rows, columns]`. So to index rows and select all columns, you must add a comma:

`data_nature_fewmissing$urbandnat[data_nature_fewmissing$nature =="yes" & data_nature_fewmissing$urbangreen =="yes",] <- "yes"`

An easier way to do this, however, is with tidyverse. We'll use `mutate` to make the new column and `case_when` to handle the multiple if-else conditions.

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data_nature_fewmissing
df %>% mutate(result = case_when(
  job == 'yes' & honorary == 'yes' ~ 'both', 
  job == 'yes' & (honorary == 'no' | is.na(honorary)) ~ 'job',
  honorary == 'yes' & (job == 'no' | is.na(job)) ~ 'honorary',
  ))
```