# Mutating based on information from two columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  sub = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102),
  trialtype = c("ReframeNeg", "ImmerseNeu", "ImmerseNeg", "ImmerseNeu", "ImmerseNeg", "ReframeNeg"),
  condition = c("Self", "Self", "Self", "Other", "Other", "Other")
)
```

How can I create a new dataframe that combines the information from the `trialtype` and `condition` columns? For example, the first observation will be 'SelfReframeNeg' after combining `trialtype` and `condition`, which I will simplify to 'selfrefneg'. The transformation mapping is as follows:

1. SelfReframeNeg = selfrefneg
2. SelfImmerseNeg = selfimmneg
3. SelfImmerseNeu = selfimmneut
4. OtherReframeNeg = socrefneg
5. OtherImmerseNeg = socimmneg
6. OtherImmerseNeu = socimmneut

This is the desired output:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  sub = c(101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102),
  trialtype = c("ReframeNeg", "ImmerseNeu", "ImmerseNeg", "ImmerseNeu", "ImmerseNeg", "ReframeNeg"),
  condition = c("Self", "Self", "Self", "Other", "Other", "Other"),
  trial = c("selfrefneg", "selfimmneut", "selfimmneg", "socimmneut", "socimmneg", "socrefneg")
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you edit your question to describe the logic that goes into this transformation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add new column based on two other columns with several conditions, character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70733211/add-new-column-based-on-two-other-columns-with-several-conditions-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a limited number of possibile combinations you could use `case_when`

```r
example %>%
  mutate(trial = paste0(condition, trialtype),
         trial = case_when(
           trial == "SelfReframeNeg" ~ "selfrefneg",
           trial == "SelfImmerseNeg" ~ "selfimmneg",
           trial == "SelfImmerseNeu" ~ "selfimmneut",
           trial == "OtherReframeNeg" ~ "socrefneg",
           trial == "OtherImmerseNeg" ~ "socimmneg",
           trial == "OtherImmerseNeu" ~ "socimmneut",
           TRUE ~ NA
         ))
#>   sub  trialtype condition       trial
#> 1 101 ReframeNeg      Self  selfrefneg
#> 2 101 ImmerseNeu      Self selfimmneut
#> 3 101 ImmerseNeg      Self  selfimmneg
#> 4 102 ImmerseNeu     Other  socimmneut
#> 5 102 ImmerseNeg     Other   socimmneg
#> 6 102 ReframeNeg     Other   socrefneg
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of an elegant solution, but in base R you can take a brute-force approach - initially combine using `paste0` and `substr` then subsequent tweaks with `gsub`:

```
# combine 
example$trial <- paste0(tolower(example$condition), 
                        substr(tolower(example$trialtype), 1, 3),
                        substr(tolower(example$trialtype), nchar(example$trialtype) - 2, nchar(example$trialtype)))
# additional tweaks 
example$trial <- gsub("other", "soc", example$trial)
example$trial <- gsub("neu", "neut", example$trial)
```

Output

```
  sub  trialtype condition       trial
1 101 ReframeNeg      Self  selfrefneg
2 101 ImmerseNeu      Self selfimmneut
3 101 ImmerseNeg      Self  selfimmneg
4 102 ImmerseNeu     Other  socimmneut
5 102 ImmerseNeg     Other   socimmneg
6 102 ReframeNeg     Other   socrefneg
```

Check for equality with desired output provided by OP:

```
all.equal(example_solution$trial, example$trial)
# [1] TRUE
```